# How do i rotate an object so that it faces away from a sphere given its position in longitude and latitude

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have a sphere and boxes which are supposed to be buildings on it. And i want to rotate the boxes (around the x y and z axis) so that they face away from the sphere just like normal buildings would given the longitude and latitude of the boxes (also the x,y,z positon).

I hope you can help me with my Problem, any help would be appreciated :)

I tried alot of rotations using longitude and latitude but none worked.
I have also thought of using the vector from the center of the Sphere to the buildings position to find out the rotation but couldn't come up with a solution.

```
  var lat = i; //-90 to 90
  var lon = j; //-180 to 180


  var height = 10;
  var width = 10;
  var length = 10;

  var xyz = getXYZ(lat, lon, sphereradius, height);

  var boxE3 = document.createElement('a-box');

  boxE3.setAttribute('material', {
    color: getRandomColor()
  });

  boxE3.setAttribute('rotation', {
    x: 0, 
    y: lat, //Rotation that needs to be correctly set.
    z: lon
  });

  boxE3.setAttribute('position', {
    x: xyz[0],
    y: xyz[1],
    z: xyz[2]
  });

  boxE3.setAttribute('scale', {
    x: length,
    y: height,
    z: width
  });
  sceneEl.appendChild(boxE3);
}
```

Actual Result:

[image]

Wanted Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Rotating an object to face away from another object.

I'd reuse the `look-at` component logic, where the "looking at" is made with a simple method:

```
object3D.lookAt(THREE.Vector3())
```

Having a box, and a sphere, just make the box `lookAt` the sphere, and rotate it around.

```
box.object3D.lookAt(spherePosition)
box.rotation.y += Math.Pi
```

Check it out in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/8q6ypr0u/16/). But I'd do it all a bit differently.

### Rotating a frame of reference around a sphere

Lets say we have a following setup.

```
<a-sphere id="earth" position="1 1 -2" radius="1.5"></a-sphere>
<a-entity id="frameOfReference" position="1 1 -2>
   <a-box position="0 0 -1.5></a-box>
</a-entity>
```

Now, the planet and the frame are in the same position. The box position is corresponding to the planets radius. It's actually facing away the planet, no matter how we rotate the frame of reference.

Why it's useful ? Because now you can rotate the frame of reference using latitude and longitude:

```
    let x = latitude
    let y = longitude + 180 // 180deg shift because z is negative
    frame.setAttribute("rotation", x + " " + y + " " + 0)
```

Check it out in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/af13nceL/6/), where the ISS is tracked using [this API](https://wheretheiss.at/).

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your answer, i have tried it out and it is exactly what i need ^^

Comment: @RezarakSL glad I could help, if all's clear feel free to mark the anwser :)

Comment: I have another question for the lookat function, it works when i initialize the box in the html file, but when i try to generate the box dynamically in the js file it doesn't work anymore. It itself doesn't throw an Error but the "box.rotation.y += Math.Pi" does. It sais: "Cannot read property 'y' of null". I'm guessing there is no property rotation after creation which may also be why the lookat function doesn't do anything? Thanks again for all your help it was very usefull to me :).

Comment: @RezarakSL you probably need to refer to `box.object3D.rotation.y` like i did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/dL4p8c3z/10/)

Comment: Since you answered my last question so well, i'd like to ask you if you can help me with my other one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56307260/how-do-i-create-a-plane-through-two-points-in-3d-space-in-a-frame. The idea behind this is to add streets to the sphere but unfortunatelly i have no idea how to go about doing it. I tried alot of things but couldn't come up with a good solution. Thanks again for your help :)